# Javascript ContextMenu in IE7

Tags: asp.net, javascript

We are using div tag in aspx and javascript functions to show context menu in our web application. In IE6 the sub menus in the context menu are getting displayed at the correct x and y coordinates what we have hard-coded in our application. But in IE7 and IE8, the sub menus are getting overlapped and in some machines the menus are going behind the window. Can any one please tell what is wrong or any other alternatives to display conext menu and submenu?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Nested popup windows</TITLE>
<script>
var firstPopupDiv = null;
var popup = null;
var vpopup = null;

function tag_onclick()
{
    var popup = window.createPopup();
    var div = popup.document.createElement("DIV");
    div.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    div.style.width = 200;
    div.style.height = 200;
    div.onclick = div_onclick;
    popup.document.body.appendChild(div);

    firstPopupDiv = div;
    vpopup = popup.document.parentWindow;
    popup.show(30, 30, 200, 200, maindiv);
}

function div_onclick()
{

    var fpopup = vpopup.createPopup();
    fpopup.document.body.innerHTML = "<div id=\"MarkupSubMenu\" style=\"position:relative\">&nbsp;&nbsp;Markups</div>";
    fpopup.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

    fpopup.show(230, 30, 200, 200, firstPopupDiv); // Not shown at 230!
}
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="maindiv" onclick="tag_onclick()">Click me</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be going wrong. You should provide code samples. One thing to be aware of is the fact that any CSS hacks you may be using in IE6 will be broken in IE7, and will cause unpredictable layout behaviors. There is also the question of what DOCTYPE you are using, etc. Be specific and provide full details and you might get some help.

Answer (score 0):

As for alternatives, there are a lot of [jQuery Context Menu](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryContextMenu) plugins for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Other than that, I'm afraid no one can really help you point out what's wrong with your code, without seeing your code...

Comment: Since the characters are limited in this forum, I am not able to post the code here. Please find the code from the below link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/jscript/thread/bb097c2d-f05e-45e4-bd4c-fa0071abccbd

Could you please reply me back in stackoverflow

Thanks in advance